# Implementing a SearchBar inside my TableView and using NSFetchedResultsController and the appropriate predicate to get searches working

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, predicate, searchbar

I have a simple TableViewController which has an add button which goes over to a ModalViewController; the user adds in text into a text field, presses save and that dismisses and the entry is added to the Entities and Attributes in Core Data and displayed in the TableViewController. It works well.

I firstly started off with another button that pulled up a UISearchBar in a Table View and I could search for results and pull that back; that worked. I then added a new tab to the bottom of the TableViewController and managed to get the search bar and table in there.

Now, I want the SearchBar at the top of the Single Table View and I want the user to be able to type and for it to dynamically search the TableView.

My fetchRequest looks like this currently for the TableView (without the searching bar):

```
 NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Transaction" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"occasion.dateOfEvent" ascending:NO selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];
    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];
    //NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY whoBy.name CONTAINS[c] %@", self.searchBar.text];
    //[fetchRequest setPredicate:pred];
    NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"occasion.dateOfEvent" cacheName:nil];
    self.fetchedResultsController = theFetchedResultsController;
    _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    return _fetchedResultsController;
```

I'm searching across the Transaction, etc. Now, the only difference between this code and my other view controller which has the search bar is the fact that the NSPredicate is uncommented. The searching works well. If I uncomment that in this code, when I run it, I get the following error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid predicate: nil RHS'
*** First throw call stack:
```

I understand what's happening because I want the TableViewController to display WITHOUT a predicate, but when I search, I went that predicate to go in effect. Any help on how to go about getting this working would be massively appreciated!

My search bar delegate method looks like this:

```
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    NSError *error;
    if (![[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error])
    {
        NSLog(@"Error in search %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    } else
    {
        [self.tView reloadData];
        [self.searchBar resignFirstResponder];
        [noResultsLabel setHidden:_fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects.count > 0];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set a predicate only if a search string is given:

```
if ([self.searchBar.text length] > 0) {
    NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY whoBy.name CONTAINS[c] %@", self.searchBar.text];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:pred];
}
```

If the search string is empty, no predicate is set and therefore all results are returned.

Comment: Thanks Martin - as always, you're a great help! That got rid of the error and breakpoints show it's getting to the searchbar method, but it's not refreshing the page, or reloading the data to show the display results. I have updated my original question to include the original searchbar methods from when the search bar was a separate UI and the difference is it's reloading data, but I thought with NSFetched, we don't need to do that.. I also don't have a tableView property in my TableViewController.. is there a way to "reload" the data when the save button is pressed?

Comment: @amitsbajaj: Could it be that `[self fetchedResultsController]` in `searchBarSearchButtonClicked` return an *old* fetched results controller? If the predicate changes, you have to *recreate* the FRC. (That is almost correct. You could also modify the fetch request.)

Comment: Thanks @Martin - I believe the fetchedResultsController is the same, I think.. but also, In the fetchRquest.. i have if (_fetchedResultsController != nil)
    {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }

I'm not fully sure what to do to get this working, sorry!

Comment: @amitsbajaj: You probably should set `_fetchedResultsController = nil` in `searchBarSearchButtonClicked`, so that the next call to `[self fetchedResultsController]` creates a *new* FRC.

Comment: thanks Martin - tried that - no change unfortunately.. when I press Search with a letter or word, it removes the keyboard but keeps the full list of items rather than just the searched terms.. sorry, i know it's sometihng not too difficult but i appreciate you taking your time to help!

Comment: I notice through Breakpoints, that the if [self fetchedResultsController] isn't actually being called, it's the else statement [self.searchBar resignFirstResponder];
        [noResultsLabel setHidden:_fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects.count > 0]; that's actually being called - not sure if that helps..

Comment: @amitsbajaj: `[self fetchedResultsController]` *is* called, because it is inside the `if()` condition.

Comment: Thanks Martin - that's true.. any idea how I can get this working? It's driving me nuts!

Comment: Hi Martin, I've got this working now. I basically created a tableView and did self.tView reloadData in the else statement of the if ![self fetchedResults, etc. Also, the setting of the _fetchedResultsController to nil made it work; I just wanted to ask you why it was that that line made it work well - I just can't get my head around why that had to be nil for this to work.. thanks Martin

Comment: @MartinR, If the search bar text length is 0, how to handle it?