# NSPredicate in UISearchController

Tags: nspredicate, searchbar, uisearchcontroller

I created a searchBar on my UITableViewController and I have an error when I try to run app. The error is at this line `NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name contains[c] %@", searchText];` The app crash at this line, the compiler says `unimplemented SQL generation for predicate : (name CONTAINS[c] "")'` What I'm doing wrong????

```
-(void)searchForText:(NSString *)searchText
{
    CoreDataStack *coreDataStack = [CoreDataStack defaultStack];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"AddEntry"];
    fetchRequest.resultType = NSDictionaryResultType;

    if (coreDataStack.managedObjectContext) {

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name contains[c] %@", searchText];
        [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];


               NSError *error = nil;
        self.filteredList = [coreDataStack.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    }
}



-(void)updateSearchResultsForSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController
{
    NSString *searchString = searchController.searchBar.text;

    [self searchForText:searchString ];

    [self.tableView reloadData];
 }
```

Comment: It seems that the search string is *empty*. Compare http://stackoverflow.com/a/19583451/1187415.

Comment: Yes martin you are right I changed predicateFormat in `NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"titluPlumb contains[c] %@", searchText];
        [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];` and everything is working!!! Thanks!!!